# Undecorated window loses native events

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I use [Decorated = false](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated) to make a frameless, borderless window with gtk#. This means adding my own drag logic and events for minimizing and closing the window, fine. However in Windows (at least), the window loses its native minimize/restore/close animations and I'm unable to minimize the window by clicking in the taskbar as you usually can.

Is there a way to have an undecorated window in gtk and still get the native minimize/restore animations or at least being able to minimize it from the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this as well.  It is my understanding (maybe incorrect) that such features are a part of the windowing for the application.  With it undecorated they simply don't exist in the taskbar.  You might be able to create "Tasks" that are available when you right-click on the taskbar icon, but I have no experience with doing so.  I believe those are technically called "JumpLists" or something like that.